# Duplicate of a question without answer

Tags: support, questions, flagging

Yesterday I flagged [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/146152/calculate-complexity-of-game-of-lifecellular-automata) with "in need of a moderator intervention" because it was the third time the author asked the very same question.

The moderator handling my flag answered: "They should edit their post. You can vote or flag such posts as duplicates of the original post". However, as far as I know, casting a closing vote or raising a flag for a duplicate can only be done with a post that already has an answer. Did I miss something? Is it possible with a post without answer?

Since the same problem happened again (but this time not by the same author) between [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/146173/shortest-walk-from-u-to-v-through-w) and [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/146174/dijkstras-algorithm-on-a-graph-with-double-weights), I would like to know the right process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops.  Sorry about that.  I don't think you missed anything.  You're right -- I don't believe you can mark it as a duplicate of a question with no answers.  I think flagging was the right thing to do -- I think you are following the right process.  Moderators can close as duplicate but you can't, and it's easy to forget that.

I apologize about the rejected flag and about the faulty feedback.  I would guess that it was likely an oversight.

(By the way, those two linked questions aren't duplicates: the first restricts to paths that go "through $w$", the second doesn't.  That makes the second much easier.)

Comment: My bad for the two linked questions. Also no problem for the flag! It wasn't even rejected (and even if it was, I mean, it's just a flag).
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Nathaniel Oh, I didn't even know closing as a duplicate of a questions without answers is a moderator exclusive operation! Thanks for pointing this out. So indeed, I agree that making a moderator flag is the right approach for this situation.